# Unable to deserialize json array to class object using jackson fasterxml in scala

Tags: java, json, scala, serialization

I am trying to serialize class object to json and deserialize json to class objects using jackson faster xml in scala. Here is my code.

```
var jsonDataString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(nodeRepoList)
var deserializedData: List[NodeRepository] = objectMapper.readValue(jsonDataString, classOf[List[NodeRepository]]);
```

The json looks as follows.

```
[ {
  "Operation" : "sample",
  "Value" : "cool",
  "TargetColumn" : "10",
  "ClassName" : "RowFilter",
  "DiagramId" : "2",
  "NodeId" : "1"
}, {
  "columnToInclude" : "sample",
  "ClassName" : "ColumnFilter",
  "DiagramId" : "2",
  "NodeId" : "1"
} ]
```

While deserializing to the class object the output is as follows. The output is in Map.It shouldnot be in the Map type. It should be deserialized to class objects.

```
[Map(NodeId -> 1, ClassName -> RowFilter, TargetColumn -> 10, Value -> cool, Operation -> sample, DiagramId -> 2)]
```

Please let me know how to resolve the issue.

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: The deserialized data should be as like this [RowFilter [ Operation: sample, Value: cool,Target:10,ClassName:RowFilter,DiagramId:2,NodeId:1 ], ColumnFilter [ columnToInclude: sample,ClassName:ColumnFilter,DiagramId:2,NodeId:1 ]] since the class is of list type. But actually am getting as Map type. How to get the deseralized data of class which is of list type instead of map type ?

Answer (score 9):

I recently had the same issue. Changing from List to Array solved my problem.
Instead of

```
classOf[List[NodeRepository]]
```

try using

```
classOf[Array[NodeRepository]]
```

Your result will be an array instead of a List, but the objects will be deserialized as **NodeRepository** instead of Map. Also converting the Array into a List in scala is pretty straight forward (**toList** method for example)